# How to set Allow-Hidden header to true to get undocumented endpoint resources in API?

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x

I am working on one API request. The API link provided by vendor they said it was undocumented endpoint, If we want to use this we need to declare "Allow-Header to true" in code somewhere.

It will be great if someone help me how to achieve this!

I have used below sample code in python to see whats is the response from the server when we request the API link:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'SEC': 'c79c321c-3061-49f1-8117-0d6f873a6f26'}
response = requests.get("https://127.0.0.1/api/configuration/log_sources", headers=headers , verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print (json_data)
```

Output of the above code:

```
*{'http_response': {'code': 404, 'message': 'We could not find the resource you requested.'}, 'details': {}, 'code': 4, 'description': '', 'message': 'Relative path (/configuration/log_sources) is not a known endpoint resource. Please refer to documentation for list of endpoint resources.'}*
```

Please help me on this. 
Thanks in advance folks.

Comment: _"Allow-Header to true" in code somewhere_ ...  what does it mean exactly. Could you provide the exact sentence they have used here.

Comment: This is point given by vendor "To use an undocumented endpoint you need to set the Allow-Hidden header to true". I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Does it mean to set the header like this? `headers = {'SEC': 'c79c321c-3061-49f1-8117-0d6f873a6f26', 'Allow-Hidden': true}`? Which sounds a bit awkward to me...

Comment: It server API token. By using that only we can authorize ourselves to server to get,post any request. It custom request header we can say.

Comment: In that case, you can add it just like @salomonderossi has demonstrated in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import requests
import json
headers = {'SEC': 'c79c321c-3061-49f1-8117-0d6f873a6f26', 'Allow-Hidden': true}
response = requests.get("https://127.0.0.1/api/configuration/log_sources", headers=headers , verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print (json_data)
```

Maybe the large and lower case needs to be adjusted or try a `1` instead of `true` in the headers...